# FormTypeExtension unit test symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms

I have an error when I test a formType which contains another formType which has a formTypeExtension.

The product type (tested class):

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('reference')
            ->add('mainImage', ImageType::class)
            ->add('ean13')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('shortDescription')
            ->add('active')
            ->add('height')
            ->add('width')
            ->add('weight')
            ->add('depth')
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('price');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\AccessException
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class
        ]);
    }

    /** @noinspection PhpMissingParentCallCommonInspection */

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_product';
    }
}
```

The image type

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                'label'      => false,
                'image_path' => 'getRealWebPath'
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\AccessException
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Image::class
        ]);
    }

    /** @noinspection PhpMissingParentCallCommonInspection */

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_image';
    }
}
```

And the ImageTypeExtension

```
class ImageTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FileType::class;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\AccessException
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined('image_path');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $imageUrl = null;
        if (isset($options['image_path'])) {
            $imagePath = $options['image_path'];
            $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();
            if ($parentData !== null) {
                $imageUrl = $parentData->$imagePath();
            }
        }
        $view->vars['image_url'] = $imageUrl;
    }
}
```

When I launch the unit test, I have this error:

> 1. tests\AppBundle\Form\ProductTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
>    Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: The option "image_path" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "inherit_data", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "multiple", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message".

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you stepped through the extension code to make sure that the buildView method is actually executing as you expect it? Wrap a try-catch around that.

Comment: The debugger never pass in the buildView method in the ImageTypeExtension class :/

Comment: Well if that method is not getting invoked, then the error is correct. At what point would you expect that to fire? I can't see any obvious reference in your posted code.

Comment: Can you show us your Unit test class ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this problem.

There's documentation that states that forms can be tested with the TypeTestCase, and it indicates that it caters to extensions too:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html#adding-custom-extensions

However, upon closer inspection, it seems that what I was wanting to enable was (as in your case) a FormTypeExtension rather than a FormExtension.

The solution was to override the getTypeExtensions() method:

```php
class CostOrNilTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    protected function getTypeExtensions(): array
    {
        return [
            new ChoiceTypeExtension(), // The missing extension
        ];
    }

    public function testCostOrNilForm(): void
    {
        // -- snip --

        // The form that had previously exploded due to the extension not being loaded...
        $form = $this->factory->create(CostOrNilType::class, $data);

        // -- snip --
    }
```

This allowed me to enable the missing form type extensions in my test and test my form.

(Whether this testing class existed at the time you asked this question, I do not know. Still, it seems to have been present since at least Symfony 3.4)